# Flutter Bloc - Button did not trigger state change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I Have a `main.dart` with its own `main_bloc.dart`, `main_event.dart` and `main_state.dart`:

```
main_event:
- AppStarted
- GoingHome
- GoingTestHome

main_State:
- StateHome
- StateTestHome

main_bloc:
Stream<MainState> mapEventToState(
    MainEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      print('mainbloc: AppStarted');
dispatch(GoingHome());
    }
    if (event is GoingHome) {
      print('mainbloc: GoingHome');
      yield StateHome();
    }
    if (event is TestHome) {
      print('mainbloc: TestHome');
      yield StateTestHome();
    }
...
}
```

in my `main.dart`:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  MainBloc _mainBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mainBloc = MainBloc();
    _mainBloc.dispatch(AppStarted());/// <-- 1
  }
...

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        builder: (_) => _mainBloc,
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Home',
          theme: ThemeData(
            ...
          ),
          home: BlocListener<MainBloc, MainState>(
              bloc: _mainBloc,
              listener: (context, state) {
                print('state changed: ${state.toString()}');
                if (state is StateHome) {  /// <-- 2
                  print('main: StateHome');
                  _mainBloc.dispatch(TestHome()); /// <-- 2.1
                } else if (state is StateTestHome) {  /// <-- 3
                  print('main: StateTestHome');
                }
              },
              child: SplashPage()),
...
```

I do a quick test:

1. when app initiated, `_mainBloc.dispatch(AppStarted())` is called, it will call `dispatch(GoingHome())` from `main_bloc`.
2. `BlocListener` detected state change('StateHome'), so:

   `print('main: StateHome');
   _mainBloc.dispatch(TestHome());`
3. `BlocListener` detected state change('StateTestHome')again, so:

   `print('main: StateTestHome');`

In console, I can see all the print message in sequence:

```
Restarted application in 1,612ms.
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: AppStarted
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: GoingHome
I/flutter (15369): state changed: StateHome
I/flutter (15369): main: StateHome
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: TestHome
I/flutter (15369): state changed: StateTestHome
I/flutter (15369): main: StateTestHome
```

So far, it run in the way I expected.

But when I take out code `2.1`, then add a button to trigger event:

```
...
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('test'),
        onPressed: () {
          _mainBloc.dispatch(TestHome());
        },
      ),
...
```

I will get the console like this:

```
Restarted application in 2,738ms.
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: AppStarted
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: GoingHome
I/flutter (15369): state changed: StateHome
I/flutter (15369): main: StateHome
I/flutter (15369):
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: TestHome ///<-- button trigger
```

I expect:

```
Restarted application in 2,738ms.
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: AppStarted
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: GoingHome
I/flutter (15369): state changed: StateHome
I/flutter (15369): main: StateHome
I/flutter (15369):
I/flutter (15369): mainbloc: TestHome ///<-- button trigger
I/flutter (15369): state changed: StateTestHome ///<-- expectation
I/flutter (15369): main: StateTestHome          ///<-- expectation
```

It seems like button interaction did not `yield` the state, or `BlocListener` did not catch the state change event.

What am I missing here? How can I resolve this?

Comment: As I know `init()` fires before the `build()`, so you dispatch your event before widget tree completely have built. Try this: `builder: (_) => _mainBloc.dispatch(AppStarted())`, in `build()` func

Comment: Did you know `BlocDelegate`? you could use It to observe the `states` and `events`, and you could free some `print` :P

Answer (score 5):

`Bloc` catches the event, but you are trying send consecutive same state. Try another yield above `yield StateTestHome();`

Like

```
yield StateIgnored(); // *****
yield StateTestHome();
```

**EDIT :** Or you can just delete ***Equatable*** abstraction.

Comment: from `StateHome` to `StateTestHome` is 2 different events. So I believe it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
The `blocListener` only listens to the event FOR its immediate `child`. What I had done is to get it to listens to events triggered by the child widget inside the `child` (the `child` of immediate `child`), so that won't happen.

to resolve this issue, create a `blocListener` for that `child` of immediate `child` itself.